# Supporting IPv6-only Networks what things should be taken care?

Tags: ios, ipv6, reachability

Regarding apple's announcement regarding iPv6 -only networks, i have some queries.

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05042016a

1) What will happen if my apps are already uploaded without ipv6 support ?

2) I am using old Reachability class, will it create any issue?

3) I am using ASIHTTP library which is using NSURLConnection.

4) If i am not using any static iP in my code but my server is on iPV4 support then will it be create any trouble ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Already Uploaded apps are working fine, actually i have not used any static ip addresses in my app.

2) Make sure in old reachability class, you have not used any addresses like 0.0.0.0.

3)It won't create any problem.

4) Not any relation with server.So server may be iPv6 or iPv4, it won't affect your app.

Comment: As far as networking connection is concerned, if we're making the connection via NSURL based classes then we're trouble free as well !